# Workaround for CFIDE Not Web Accessible for AJAX and Flash Built-Ins

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Several pieces of ColdFusion functionality - media player and multi file uploader - are predicated on JavaScript libraries being available at `/CFIDE/scripts`, even if the `scriptsrc` is configured in `Application.cfc`. See the bug here for a point of reference: http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/83328

Unfortunately exposing the CFIDE directory as-is from a ColdFusion installation is a security risk. So I'm trying to decide the right path forward to enable my application's use of this functionality whilst not exposing this hole. The wrinkle is that I am shipping a product so I am trying to imagine a solution that I can either automate with an installer or document easily enough that a system administrator should have no trouble setting up.

These are the options I've come up with:

1. Document to, or have the installer, create an empty directory and virtually map it as `/CFIDE`. Copy the contents of the `scripts` folder from the ColdFusion installation beneath it.
2. Distribute just the files I need modified and ensure the referenced .swfs are in the whatever location it's changed to (paths are relative to CFIDE/scripts):

   1. `/ajax/package/cffileupload_swf.js`
   2. `/ajax/package/cfmediaplayer.js`

Which option seems better? Or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply map the full scripts folder.  Rather than map /CFIDE, map /CFIDE/scripts. This would expose the scripts folder, but /CFIDE wouldn't exist at all.

Another similar option is to copy the scripts folder to somewhere "common" and again create a /CFIDE/scripts mapping to this folder.

Both of these solutions are virtually identical, but the second is probably better for the truly paranoid.

Comment: is it possible to create a mapping named "/CFIDE/scripts"? Can't see how to do this on IIS through the GUI at least - could it be scripted?

Comment: +1 because your comment led me to figure out IIS does nested Virtual Directories. Did not know this. Now for Apache...

Comment: Apache can do it too as such: Alias /CFIDE/scripts "/path/to/CFIDE/scripts"

Comment: The only thing I disagree with in this answer is that the second option it "probably better". I don't think it is. The second option makes upgrading a PITA. The first option is better, even if you are paranoid.

Comment: @Jason, yeah I use the first solution for exactly that reason.  It is a pain to update. The second option; "probably better" and "for the truly paranoid" are not intended to be separated. ;)