# "onComplete attribute must be javascript function name" what am i typing wrong?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm trying to run a piece of JavaScript code on completion of a song in the `<cfmediaplayer>` tag but whenever i put "playNext()" into the onComplete attribute it provides me with an error telling me it must be a proper name, but that is the proper name? Anybody know where i might be going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playNext(){
        <cfoutput>
            var #ToScript(URL.current, "trackNo")#;
        </cfoutput>
        trackNo++;
        $("#" + trackNo).click();
    }
</script>

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;">
    <cfoutput query="getmusic" maxrows="1">
        <cfmediaplayer name="musicPlayer" source="/artists/music/#music_location#" autoplay="yes" height="500" width="500" title="#artist_name# - #music_name#" onComplete="playNext"></cfmediaplayer>
    </cfoutput>
</div>
```

This is my code, however i just noticed (using the Web Developer toolbar) that it is saying playNext is undefined, yet clearly i DO have it defined there as displayed. I'm wondering what I may have done wrong, as far as i'm aware my JavaScript looks OK but i'm a novice when it comes to JS so i've probably made a simple mistake.

Comment: The complete code or some more code fitting into the context would help us to help you.

Comment: all im asking is why is it telling me i've got to use a correct function name when "playNext()" is my function name?

Comment: it won't solve the problem but get rid of `<cfoutput query="getmusic" maxrows="1">` and limit the query results from the cfquery and use `source="/artists/music/#getMusic.music_location[1]#"`

Comment: is this a shorthand way of outputting just one row then? if so i'll continue to do this in future. Cheers.

Comment: I just showed you.  query.column[1]

Comment: Yeah, that just returns the first column instead of just one result. The reason i used the output query is so it fetches the correct track.

Comment: no, it doesn't fetch one, it only loops one. the query still has the entire record set. to limit the query results you do that in cfquery's maxRows or write it in your query with the top, limit, rownum, or whatever the sql is for your RDBMS.

Comment: Yeah just realised this haha, i made an error with my code, my bad.

Comment: we all do it, welcome to the club. :) no need to be standoffish when people give you advice.

Comment: I know i apologise, just very stressed. Coding (especially JavaScript) can really rile you at times!

Comment: back to the topic at hand, do you have a virtual folder established for CFIDE in your website? It's often needed for client side stuff coldfusion creates.

Comment: Now i'm lost, i'm not entirely sure what folder name i would be looking for in particular?

Comment: usually http://yourdomain.com/cfide/  it would be a virtual folder established in your web server, iis?

Comment: Would this be only if the site is live? Currently i'm using the site as localhost as it is still in production.

Comment: I'm guessing you still need the virtual mapping but i've never run CF localhost before.  whenever CF writes JS to the browser, usually with cfform, all the scripts are found in the cfide folder so if your site doesn't map to it, the browser can't see them. i'm looking for documentation but i'm only finding the lockdown guide and web server instructions for setting up the mapping.

Comment: Ah i don't use cfform tags i use the HTML ones, im currently building onto a site as part of an apprenticeship so i'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to the backend part of sites, i have dabbled with settings in IIS but only to get the site on localhost.

Comment: But the cfide folder is required for any of the coldfusion javascript functions. are you using any of the `ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.xyz` functions to control the songs?  I could be wrong but I suspect you need a cfide mapping.

Comment: Unless i've done it without knowing then no, just using the defined attributes within the `<cfmediaplayer>` tag itself, i'll have a look for the folder now, any idea as to where it would be located usually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339749/workaround-for-cfide-not-web-accessible-for-ajax-and-flash-built-ins

Comment: I've managed to locate a cfide folder and within the scripts folder it has an ajax folder which has another folder with 3 scripts in, is this what i'm looking for? Ill have a read of that post.

Comment: can you post your generated JavaScript? Use the Developer tools in Chrome/Firefox to pull that up

Answer (score 1):

use `onComplete="playNext"` not `"playNext()"`

Comment: Already tried both, posted my JS to see if anybody could possibly spot an error which I can't see myself.

Comment: It might help if your playNext function was defined in the <head></head> of your page (possibly it is, it's unclear from your code sample)

Comment: it isn't defined in the head, should i try it in there just for testings sake?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling "playNext()" in the onComplete attribute as playNext with no quotations or brackets. If that does not work use playNext(). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: i've tried just playNext before, that's the closest I have to anything working, as it doesn't throw an error but it does prevent the player from loading. It's frustrating me now, been trying to get it to work for a fair few days but this is all i need to finish.

Comment: Then it will be something in your function PlayNext. Make sure you look over your code and make sure everything is how you want it to be. If it is not throwing an error it will be your function not doing what you intend it to do. I had the same problem with collision detection but it was me being stupid on my algorithm.

Comment: what have you got your .click() method on? (button etc?).

Comment: on a `<a>` tag containing the link to the next song.

Comment: try adding a $ as your perameter of your playNext function.

Comment: Just tried this and unfortunately it's still doing the same thing :/ all i need to do is write a bit of JS code which adds 1 onto the URL variable which controls the row of the query that the media player takes the data from. Who would of thought it could be so difficult haha

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think it has to do with a CFIDE mapping.

The CFIDE/Scripts folder is needed for a lot of the client side controls ColdFusion creates.

Some CFForm elements like the date picker, multiple file upload, cfajaxproxy, cfmediaplayer, etc require these scripts to be mapped or copied to the site.

Here is a SO question that may help.

[Workaround for CFIDE Not Web Accessible for AJAX and Flash Built-Ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339749/workaround-for-cfide-not-web-accessible-for-ajax-and-flash-built-ins)

Here is a general [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=cfide%20mapping) on the subject.

Try a simple script to mute the player you get any 'Coldfusion is undefined' errors.  something like

```
<script language ="javascript">
    ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.setMute('musicPlayer', true);
</script>
```

Comment: So is this basically saying any value which you provide an external source away from the tag itself it won't work because it needs access directly to a script from the cfide folder to run it? I'm kinda confused.

Comment: I don't know how cfmediaplayer is written but the client player needs to call a javascript function onComplete so it would reason that the JS required to do that would reside with the rest of ColdFusions' javascripts, the CFIDE/scripts folder.

Comment: Ah i see the script to allow onComplete to run isn't present which is why it's saying any function i place in there is undefined, i'll do some research.

Comment: @LeeB I updated my question with a simple test.  I haven't tested it but I copied the syntax from a working example on the interwebs.

Comment: I placed the script above where the `<cfmediaplayer>` is situated and upon loading it didn't mute the player, but also it didn't cause any errors either.

Comment: did you change 'PlayerName' to 'musicPlayer'?  I should have done that in my code, my bad.

Comment: yeah haha, after noticing it i did, but still no change to the outcome. Seems like it's not responding but not throwing errors either.

Comment: here are some other examples you can try http://coldfusionexamples.com/category/cfmediaplayer/ edit: updated link

Comment: Tried them and left it as the example to save me making any typo's and it still won't work, wondering what could be causing it.

Comment: I've found the virtual CFIDE directory in my IIS, how and what exactly do i need to do to map the required scripts?

Comment: did you find the physical folder or did you find it as a virtual in IIS?  if it is already a virtual to your site then my answer isn't correct.  if it is a physical folder, see the google search I posted above, a lot of those results will help.

Comment: I found it physically and also in the virtual directory i have CFIDE/ with many folders including the scripts one

Comment: if you go to http://yourwebsite/cfide/administrator you should probably see the cfadmin login.  if you do then... this answer isn't going to help except, that you learned about CFIDE which is still important to know about.

Comment: I've just tried this and it returns an error so looks like your solution may be what i need, it tries to load "mywebsite/cfide/administrator/index.cfm"

Comment: How about the IP address rather than the physical address.

Comment: i would probably just use the same method you're using to access the rest of  your site, IP, domain, localhost, whatever.

Comment: well i don't think it's accessing the login page via the link you said to type so something might be up